# Group and compress

Tags: views

[image]

I am trying to add the salary of all employees by company wise using views aggregator plus module. Applied group and compress group function on company and sum group function on salary. But the result is not of expected . Some company names are not grouped completely.

Please tell me where I am doing wrong

Comment: on salary, do not choose 'group', do choose COLUMN function SUM

Comment: Also try removing Sort criteria, it often interferes with Aggregation.

Comment: I tried but still its not working. Content type is webform submission data. Does views aggregator plus need any supporting modules.The behaviour of this module is not constant.  Also please tell me is there any other way group company names and add salary of respective employees in that company.